# Format Painter for kendo editor?

Tags: c#-4.0, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

My client is requesting to have an format editor like functionality for kendo editor.What i need is to have a button in the editor and when the user select some text and copy the style of that text. once he select another text and apply the previous selected text style to current text.I am ok with the jquery solution as well. Is there any way to achieve this?